# Heroku app works briefly then throws me errors in the console

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have a chat app made with react socket.io and node/express which works as intended

Live app deployed here [Live app deployed here][https://reactchatappdanwilstrop.netlify.app/]

After using a couple of times the app stops working and sends me the below error (mulitple times) in the console.  The back end is deployed to Heroku

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://danreactchat.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NVpH332' from origin 'https://reactchatappdanwilstrop.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have called CORS as below

```
app.use(cors());
```

If i leave the app and return a time later it works again.  Are there limits on heroku? Surely they should be higher than me using it a few times if there are?

Does anyone know how to solve this issue please or what the problem may be?